# Firebase simulator does not allow "read" but it is working in production

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

During "read" at path /pending-posts using Simulator to test the Firebase-security rules, I found rules are working fine in production, but simulator shows read denied. I spend several hours to identify, real problem exists with simulator.Below is my Security Rules.

```
    {
      "rules": {
        "pending-posts":{
          ".read":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)",
          ".write": "auth.uid != null"
        },
      }
    }I am using custom authentication and below is my token
    {
      "uid": "SYS1904",
      "iss": "firebase-adminsdk-h08vu@gooonj-1293e.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "sub": "firebase-adminsdk-h08vu@gooonj-1293e.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "aud": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
      "iat": 1482300927,
      "exp": 1482302127,
      "claims": {
        "empCode": "SYS1904",
        "empName": "Anil Kumar",
        "role": "moderator",
        "photo": "SYS1904-5b8af31fba.jpg"
      }
    }Below is my database JSON-
    { 
  "pending-posts" : {
    "-KZzww9RSz_zxJW-ZxHY" : {
      "author" : "Sharma",
      "body" : "frank",
      "commentCount" : 0,
      "likeCount" : 0,
      "starCount" : 0,
      "timeStamp" : 1482836658167,
      "title" : "hi",
      "uid" : "TYS65598981",
      "url" : ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the simulator that shows it allowing the read (include the current data and the path you are reading). And then can you also include the minimal code that is denied reading from the same location?

Comment: Hello Frank, simulator already denied 'read' permission so how I can show the screen shots which shows simulator 'read ' allowed.In production it is working fine so issue. But I got stuck at another issue,as Firebase rules says,You can add privilege to the node as you go down to that node. I gave .write permission to a node for 'moderator'(an attribute of custom Token) ,this node contents several attributes.I want to give another .write permission to some attributes for all user(not restricted to moderator only)at this node.Is it possible??

Comment: I am using Firebase Android SDK to read from my app.

Comment: Sorry for misreading your post. In that case: can you *edit* your question to include the code that successfully reads data and show a screenshot of the simulator denying the same read operation?

Comment: { 
  "pending-posts" : {
    "-KZzww9RSz_zxJW-ZxHY" : {
      "author" : "Sharma",
      "body" : "frank",
      "commentCount" : 0,
      "likeCount" : 0,
      "starCount" : 0,
      "timeStamp" : 1482836658167,
      "title" : "hi",
      "uid" : "TYS65598981",
      "url" : ""
  }
}